# Name node and Datanode are not starting

Tags: java, hadoop, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed hadoop in Ubuntu and created the dir for namenode and data node. But I ma not able to see the namnode and data node is not running.

```
hduser@sanjeebpanda:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ jps
9445 Jps
5311 JobHistoryServer
hduser@sanjeebpanda:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
14/11/09 21:14:34 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your **platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
Starting namenodes on []
localhost: starting namenode,** logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.4.0/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-sanjeebpanda.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.4.0/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-sanjeebpanda.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.4.0/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-sanjeebpanda.out
14/11/09 21:14:52 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-sanjeebpanda.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.4.0/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-sanjeebpanda.out
hduser@sanjeebpanda:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ jps
**10134 NodeManager
10007 ResourceManager
10436 Jps
5311 JobHistoryServer**
```

But I can see the  both the directory have been created.

```
hduser@sanjeebpanda:/usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs$ ls -ltr
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 hduser hadoop 4096 Nov  9 21:13 namenode
drwx------ 2 hduser hadoop 4096 Nov  9 21:14 datanode
hduser@sanjeebpanda:/usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs$
```

Comment: Sorry,I was wrong in Core site xml. It worked now.hduser@sanjeebpanda:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ jps
12240 NameNode
12715 ResourceManager
13056 Jps
12565 SecondaryNameNode
12387 DataNode
5311 JobHistoryServer
12842 NodeManager

Comment: I am not able to locate hdfs path. Can you help to locate that.I have to put a file using hadoop fs -put command. I am unable to locate the direcotry.hduser@sanjeebpanda:/usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs$ ls -ltr
drwxr-xr-x 3 hduser hadoop 4096 Nov  9 21:13 namenode
drwx------ 2 hduser hadoop 4096 Nov  9 21:14 datanode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow this link , your problem will definitely solve

http://codesfusion.blogspot.in/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: Thanks That Helped me a lot. How to take care of the first unrequired line.(Native code loadr)hduser@sanjeebpanda:~$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hduser/
14/11/10 03:08:18 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup         11 2014-11-10 03:07 /user/hduser/abc.dat

Answer (score 1):

//Regarding listing files

You are using `ls`, which lists files in local directory

You have to use `hadoop fs -ls` to list files in hdfs

Comment: +1. i think this is correct answer for his question.